# HTML button with image use of alt

Tags: html

I have the following:

```html
<button class="create" type="submit" border="0" id="retry-btn" onclick="retryJournal()">
<img alt="Retry" src="styles/default/images/arrow-clock.svg"/>
</button>
```

As you can see the image has an `alt` to popup the word "Retry".

However, this does not work.  Any ideas?

Also, the button has a border, how do I get rid of the border?  (I have tried `border="0"`).

Comment: Could you include the `retryJournal()` function?

Comment: Please add `retryJournal() ` function `<script>your function code</script>` code. probably use jQuery .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alt` for an HTML `<img>` element is used to specify an alternate text if the image fails to load. So "retry" will not be the appropriate alt text here.

You can instead use the `title` attribute for the `<button>` so that it acts as a tooltip.

For removing the borders of the button, you can do it via CSS:

```
button#retry-btn { border:0 }
```

So with these changes, your HTML should look like:

```
<button class="create" 
        type="submit" 
        id="retry-btn" 
        title="Retry" 
        aria-label="Retry" 
        onclick="retryJournal()"
    >
     <img alt="clock" src="styles/default/images/arrow-clock.svg"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To remove button border you can use style as `style="border-width:0px;background-color: transparent;"` in button tag.**

```html
<button class="create" type="submit" style="border-width:0px;background-color: transparent;" id="retry-btn" onclick="retryJournal()"><img alt="Retry" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634315-48f5414c3ad9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" width=40% hieght=40% /></button>
```